# what does 3 and 4 length tuple specifies in numpy array shape?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am unable to understand that if shape tuple has length 3 or 4 then what does it mean?

For example if write

**Case1**

```
`np.ones((2))`      #[1., 1.]
```

**Case2**

`np.ones((2,2))`    #[[1., 1.],
                      [1., 1.]]

**Case3**

```
`np.ones((2,2,2))`   #[[[1., 1.],
                     [1., 1.]],

                     [[1., 1.],
                      [1., 1.]]]
```

**Case4**

```
`np.ones((2,2,2,2))`  #[[[[1., 1.],
                    [1., 1.]],

                    [[1., 1.],
                     [1., 1.]]],


                     [[[1., 1.],
                      [1., 1.]],

                      [[1., 1.],
                       [1., 1.]]]]
```

Here in case 1 can specify the number of columns when length of tuple is 1, and when length is 2 we can specify the number of columns and rows as in case 2. 
What does tuple of length 3 and 4 specifies here?

Comment: Length 3: 3-dimensional array; length 4: 4-dimensional array.

Comment: Track the use of [].  Rows and columns are terms we use for 2d arrays, but aren't formally part of the numpy description.

Comment: Using different dimensions can make the examples clearer, for example `np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)` and `np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)`.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a n-dimensional vector. So using a length-3 tuple defines a 3 dimensional vector, and using a length4 tuple defines a 4 dimensional vector.